# Window.location is giving error in prerender

Tags: angular, angular-universal

when i add window.location in my code it starts giving the following error when running npm run prerender

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: window is not defined
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at StepsGuard.canActivate
```

i have other places with window and work fine but in canActivate not.

canActivete window usage

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const param1 = urlParams.get('param1')
const param2 = urlParams.get('param2')
```

Comment: Node doesn’t have a window object (it’s not a browser), so you’ll have to either mock it or conditionally skip that code if it runs on the server.

Comment: @MikeOne But why do other places with window work? like window.scroll(0,0) in any.component.ts